# Not able to display the table content using Jsoup and display it in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7

Here my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class CollegeOfScience {
    private static Iterable<Elements> url;

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, SQLException, InterruptedException {
        Document doc;
        //Load a Document from a URL
        //doc = Jsoup.connect("https://science.swansea.ac.uk/intranet/attendance/timetable/" ).get();
        //Load a Document from a File
        File input = new File("/temp/input.htm");
        doc = Jsoup.parse(input,"UTF-8","https://science.swansea.ac.uk/intranet/attendance/timetable/" );
        // System.out.println(doc);
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println(title);
        //System.out.println(doc);
        //Elements urls = doc.select("a");
        for(Element table : doc.select("table.timetable")) {  
            for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                Elements tds = row.select("td");
                if (tds.size() > 1) {
                    System.out.println(tds.get(0).text()+":"+tds.get(3).text());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Are you getting an error message? What result do you expect?

Comment: the problem is Iam able to get the source file only but I want to get the content of the site. Iam new in java as well as with Jsoup.I hope you can help me.